# How can I apply multiple TextDecorations?

Tags: wpf, richtextbox

All the examples I've seen for setting Underline, Overline, or Strikethrough all look something like this:

```
// setting underline
textRange.ApplyPropertyValue(Inline.TextDecorationsProperty, 
                             TextDecorations.Underline);

// clearing underline
textRange.ApplyPropertyValue(Inline.TextDecorationsProperty, null );
```

This seems overly simplistic to me; the `TextDecorationsProperty` returns a *collection* of decorations - you can have `Overline`, `Underline` and `Strikethrough` all applied at the same time; setting them like this wipes out the entire collection.

This is what I have for **toggling** them by `TextDecorationLocation`:

```
var textRange = new TextRange(tb.Selection.Start, tb.Selection.End);
var tdp = textRange.GetPropertyValue(Inline.TextDecorationsProperty);
var textDecorations = tdp.Equals(DependencyProperty.UnsetValue)
                      ? new TextDecorationCollection()
                      : tdp as TextDecorationCollection 
                        ?? new TextDecorationCollection();

var strikethroughs = textDecorations.Where(d => d.Location == TextDecorationLocation.Strikethrough)
                                    .ToList();
if (strikethroughs.Any())
{
   foreach (var strike in strikethroughs)
   {
      textDecorations.Remove(strike);
   }
}
else
{
   textDecorations.Add(TextDecorations.Strikethrough);
}

textRange.ApplyPropertyValue(Inline.TextDecorationsProperty, textDecorations);
```

Is this a good way to go about this, or am I making it overly complicated?

Comment: Would you care for pure xaml solution?

Comment: Apologies I misread the post, the xaml solution I had would only allow one text decoration at a time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to toggle decorations on and off whilst allowing them to be combined you could do the following:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Content="Underline" Click="Underline" />
        <Button Content="Strikethrough"  Click="Strikethrough" />
        <Button Content="Baseline" Click="Baseline" />
        <Button Content="Overline"  Click="Overline" />
    </StackPanel>
    <RichTextBox x:Name="tb" Grid.Row="1" />
</Grid>
```

and then in the code

```
        private void Underline(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.SetDecorations(new TextRange(this.tb.Selection.Start, this.tb.Selection.End), TextDecorations.Underline);
    }

    private void Strikethrough(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.SetDecorations(new TextRange(this.tb.Selection.Start, this.tb.Selection.End), TextDecorations.Strikethrough);
    }

    private void Baseline(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.SetDecorations(new TextRange(this.tb.Selection.Start, this.tb.Selection.End), TextDecorations.Baseline);
    }

    private void Overline(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.SetDecorations(new TextRange(this.tb.Selection.Start, this.tb.Selection.End), TextDecorations.OverLine);
    }

    private void SetDecorations(TextRange textRange, TextDecorationCollection decoration)
    {
        var decorations = textRange.GetPropertyValue(Inline.TextDecorationsProperty) as TextDecorationCollection
                          ?? new TextDecorationCollection();

        decorations = decorations.Contains(decoration.First())
                          ? new TextDecorationCollection(decorations.Except(decoration))
                          : new TextDecorationCollection(decorations.Union(decoration));

        textRange.ApplyPropertyValue(Inline.TextDecorationsProperty, decorations);
    }
```

This code uses the existing decoration set and then either unions or set excepts the current decoration based on whether it is already attached - allowing the decoration to be toggled on/off.